# How to assign values to a string?

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, vector

I have a loop running on multiple workstations, each loop is dealing with 5 different classes, when the results is acquired it is to save the result with the name of the classes it used.

For example on workstation 1 I am using:

```
class1 = 1;
class2 = 10;

%code that will run on all images associated with classes 1:10
% final_result from all 10 classes is calculated here
```

I want to save this now, with the name such as:

```
result_1_10 = final_result;
save result_1_10 result_1_10;
```

I can do this manually but its becoming very difficult to change the values on all machines after one value is changed, I would rather it save these and pick up the numbers from the two variables `class1` and `class2`.

Here is what I tried:

```
['result_' num2str(class1) '_' num2str(class2)];
```

This would give me `result_1_10`. Which is what I wanted but it is a string, rather than a variable, so I cannot assign the result value to it

```
['result_' num2str(class1) '_' num2str(class2)] = final_result;
```

Would give the error:

> Error: An array for multiple LHS assignment cannot contain
>   LEX_TS_STRING.

I even tried `str2num(num2str(class1))` but that would also give an error.

How do I actually do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you *can* do this, it is [very much discouraged by The Mathworks themselves](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html). Any time you are trying to store information about what a variable contains *within* the variable name itself, that's a sign that maybe things should be rearranged a bit. Maybe consider using a different data structure.

Consider for example using a `struct` where you keep the `classes` as fields and the `result` as a field.

```
S.class1 = 1;
S.class2 = 10;
S.result = final_result;
```

You could then even create an array of structs holding your data.

```
S = struct('class1', {1, 2, 1}, ...
           'class2', {10, 11, 10}, ...
           'result', {rand(10), rand(10), rand(10)});
```

Then you could grab all results when `class1` was 1:

```
S([S.class1 == 1]);
```

Or all results when `class1` as 1 and `class2` was 10

```
S([S.class1 == 1] & [S.class2 == 10]);
```

---

If you insist on doing it the way that you've laid out, you'll have to use [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) or [`assignin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) to do that. Also, [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) is often more concise than string concatenations.

```
variable = sprintf('result_%d_%d', class1, class2);
eval([variable, '= final_result;']);
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. After the ``eval([variable, '= final_result;']);`` statement I have achieved the end result, that is assign the value to the name generated. What is the purpose of the ``assignin`` function after that?

Comment: @StuckInPhD Did you read the entire post? I would recommend trying the other approach. That being said the `assignin` statement does the exact same thing so it's an alternative.

Comment: Yes, I did read the post and your alternative method, I was just curious. Regarding the alternative, I could save everything inside a struct upto the line: ``S.variable = sprintf('result_%d_%d', class1, class2);`` but this would be in string, and I am back to where I started, how do I assign this new name to my final_result to be saved? Sorry if I misunderstood anything

Comment: @StuckInPhD If you want to convert all of your existing `result_x_y` variables to the struct versions, you will have to use `eval` (like in the last part of the question) to accomplish this. Then once they are in the struct, you will never have to use `eval` again!   `eval(sprintf('S.variable = result_%d_%d;', class1, class2));`